# Erlang HTTP: How do you include Body in an Inets or Ibrowse request?

Tags: http, erlang, inets

I am currently using Inets with the following request:

```
http:request(put, {Url, [{"User-Agent", UA}, {"Content-type", 
             "application/json"}]}, Bodytext, []),
```

But the request fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you call `inets:start().` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ibrowse:start().`

`ibrowse:send_req(Url, Headers, put, Body).`

OR

`ibrowse:send_req(Url, Headers, put, Body, Options).`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http:request(put, {Url, [{"User-Agent", UA}], "application/json", Bodytext}, [], [])

Comment: Can you use wireshark or tcpdump to determine if the request is reaching your server? Also, can you successfully perform the request with curl?